# understanding android methods

Tags: java, android

i am pretty much new to android programming.. i can write basic app.. maybe just for kids to play with, now when i want to write complex app like working with remote databases and parsing data.. i don't really know how it works because i Google for code templates to use and i don't really know how most for the methods work and infant most of them i dunno what they do. for example

```
public class IMService extends Service implements IAppManager, IUpdateData {
//  private NotificationManager mNM;

public static final String TAKE_MESSAGE = "Take_Message";
public static final String FRIEND_LIST_UPDATED = "Take Friend List";
public ConnectivityManager conManager = null; 
private final int UPDATE_TIME_PERIOD = 15000;
//  private static final int LISTENING_PORT_NO = 8956;

private String rawFriendList = new String();


ISocketOperator socketOperator = new SocketOperator(this);

private final IBinder mBinder = new IMBinder();
private String username;
private String password;
private String userKey;
private boolean authenticatedUser = false;
 // timer to take the updated data from server
private Timer timer;

private NotificationManager mNM;


public class IMBinder extends Binder {
    public IAppManager getService() {
        return IMService.this;
    }

}
```

}

most of the methods implemeted here are created customly.. 
i just wanna know the tricks

if there is any tutorial out there maybe a video tutorial.. 
please let me know.. it would save me..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the piece of code, it looks like it is a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

> A Service is an application component representing either an
>   application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not
>   interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other
>   applications to use.

Given your first paragraph, I highly recommend that you start learning from scratch if you plan to connect your apps to database, etc.

The official tutorials are here: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: Thanks.. that was awesome.. i still need one me help.. can u help me modify a php script to speak latest version of php n mysqli.. cos i learned with latest versions.. And i cant modify if i dont speak the older versions of php.. thanks in advance

Comment: You should ask a new question and tag it appropriately. PHP is not my strong suit. :)